# Graviton polarization in higher dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, polarization, degrees-of-freedom

It's not difficult to see that the graviton in $D$ spacetime dimensions has $(D-3)D/2$ polarizations. In $D=4$ there are two $\epsilon^{\pm}_{\mu\nu}$. What I find curious is that in $D=4$ I can actually pick $\epsilon^{\pm}_{\mu\nu}=\epsilon^{\pm}_{\mu}\epsilon^{\pm}_{\nu}$ where $\epsilon^{\pm}_{\mu}$ are the two polarizations (of definite elicity $\pm1$) for a massless spin-1 particle like the photon. In higher dimension this doesn't seem possible since the photon has $D-2$ polarizations so that the number $(D-2)(D-1)/2$ of $\epsilon^{\lambda}_{\mu}\epsilon^{\lambda^\prime}_{\mu}$ pairs doesn't match the number $(D-3)D/2$ of graviton polarization. Well, unless somehow I consider only a smaller subset of them, say adding a constraint or removing one of them
$$(D-2)(D-1)/2-1=(D-3)D/2$$
as in $D=4$ where $\epsilon^{+}_{\mu}\epsilon^{-}_{\mu}$ is discarded having zero elicity.

Is there an analogous constructions for $\epsilon^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of the spin-1 polarizations $\epsilon^\sigma_\mu$ in higher dimensions?
I suspect that something similar may happen only if I involve polarizations of higher elicity as well.

Comment: Sorry, should there be an absolute value sign: $|(D-3)D/2|$. Because the number of polarizations turns out to be negative in the case of D=2(2-dimensional gravity)!

Comment: @BastamTajik there is no absolute sign, as in $D\leq 3$ there is no physical polarization and in fact no propagating graviton. The formula holds as it is for the dimensions where it makes sense to talk about graviton's polarizations, i.e. for $D\geq 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, the current use of the word helicities happens only when one is looking at some representation of $SU(2)$.

1) Now, a first point of view is to try to go back to representations of $ \otimes^n SU(2)$, when working with representations of $SO(D-2)$. In the best case, you will have different kind of "helicities".

Suppose we work with $D=6$, so spin-$1$ massless particles are in the fundamental representation of $SO(4)$, which I write $4$. In term of $SU(2) \otimes SU(2)$ representations, this gives : $4 \to (2,2)$

[here I write the number of states in the representations]

So, multiplying photon representations gives $4 \times 4 \to (2,2) \times (2,2) = (3,3) + (1,3) + (3,1) + (1,1)$

$(3,3)$ is the graviton traceless symmetric representation that we are looking for, with $9 = \dfrac{6 (6-3)}{2}$

So here photons have "helicities" $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$, while gravitons have "helicities" $(0 \pm 1, 0 \pm 1)$

Gravitons states  could be written from photons states, for instance :

$(+1,+1) =   (+1,+1) (+1,+1)$

$(-1,-1) =   (-1,-1) (-1,-1)$

$(+1,-1) =   (+1,-1) (+1,-1)$

$(-1,+1) =   (-1,+1) (-1,+1)$

$(+1,0) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} [ (+1,+1) (+1,-1) + (+1,-1) (+1,+1)]$

$(0,0) =  \frac{1}{ 2} [ (+1,-1) (+1,-1) + (+1,-1) (-1,+1) + (-1,+1) (+1,-1) + (-1,+1) (-1,+1)]$

and so on.

2) A second point of view is to work directly with the representations of $SO(D-2)$

Let us use this (french) [Lie group on-line tool](http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html) (Université de Poitiers). Choose $D3 (SO(6))$, "Tensor product decomposition" (then "proceed"). Let's type $(1,0,0) \times (1,0,0)$, (then "start"), and you get $(2,0,0) + (0,1,1)+(0,0,0)$. Here we are working with Dynkin indices.

So $(2,0,0)$ is the graviton symmetric traceless representation, and it is also the highest weight state of the representation. You may get the other states of the representation by substracting with the simple roots you may directly from the Cartan matrix of $D3= SO(6) = SU(4)$ (they are the lines of the Cartan matrix) until you get no positive number. Here the simple roots are $(2,-1,0), (-1,2,-1), (0,-1,2)$. So, for instance, substracting the first root, you get the state $(2,0,0) - (2,-1,0) = (0,1,0)$, and so on.

So each state for the gravitons (or the photons) could be represented by $3$ integers, so it is an alternative way to classify the states into a given representation.

Comment: thank you for the clear and illuminating answer. I must say that I am still a bit confused by the word elicity. In $D=4$ it's associated to the representation of $SO(2)=U(1)$ and not of $SU(2)$. I see that you are selecting the abelian $U(1)$ subgroup of the $SU(2)$ as definition of the elicity, why is it so? In the case of $D=4$ this is OK since the states annihilate the remaining part of the little group, $ISO(2)$, under which the $U(1)$ in left invariant. Moreover, the little group isn't only $SO(D-2)$. The rest must be annihilated analogously to $D=4$ to avoid a continuum of states?

Comment: Actually, the best definition for helicity is probably given by referring to a single $SO(2)$ subgroup inside the little group, the one that survives when we drop the extra dimensions. I am basically thinking to do a dimensional reduction. Ah, there is probably a factor of 2 missing in your definition where the photon has helicity $(\pm1,\pm1)$ the graviton would have $(0\pm2,0\pm2)$.
Anyway, from your example it seems that the graviton is going to be always in the traceless symmetric combination since from $D-2$ photon polarizations we would get the desired $(D-2)(D-1)/2-1=D(D-3)/2$, no?

Comment: ...and I am still confused. I I do a dimensional reduction of a $6D$-graviton $h_{\mu\nu}$ to $D=4$ I get 1 graviton, 2 massless vectors, and 3 scalars that is 9 d.o.f. as expected. So I'd like to see what $SO(2)$ inside $SO(4)$ gives that assignment of helicity $2+2\times2+1+1+1$.

Comment: Maybe it is not a good idea to extend the concept of helicity to other dimensions than $D=4$... I only here considered a indice of a state in a given representation of $SU(2)$ (If there are $2$ states, there are $2$ "helicies").Yes, $ISO(2)$ is the whole symmetry group, and $SO(2)$ is the physical symmetry group (the translation part corresponds to the gauge symmetry). Yes, the graviton is always in the traceless symmetric representation of $SO(D-2)$. Dimensional reduction is OK, but it is an other process. Your original question was more how to build gravitons states from photon states.